# Where does convolution fit in DFT?

Tags: convolution, dft

I am trying to understand where does the convolution fit in Discrete Fourier Transform. I know that convolution is *producing a third signal from two other signals.* I also know that DFT transforms one signal from time to frequency domain.

So, what is the relationship between the two (if any)?

Comment: In Fourier space convolution is a simple multiplication, so to make convolution of two signals with equal length you should make their FFT, multiply them, make inverse FFT of product. Absolutely correlated signals will give you a large peak in zero shift value of convolution.

Answer (score 4):

FFT and DFT are a faster way to implement convolution.
Since convolution in time domain corresponds to [multiplication in the Fourier domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), you replace the sliding-window based implementation of convolution (in time domain) by a pointwise multiplication (in Fourier domain). This avoids you an extra inner loop over the input data and saves time.

With respect to boundary conditions, there is a minor difference with finite-length signals.
Using the convolution theorem to compute a convolution product in the Fourier domain implicitely assumes that the input data is periodic, i.e., when you reach the right end of the signal you re-enter by its leftmost part. This is also known as *circular convolution*.
If you need to have a convolution of explicitely non-periodic signals, you can add zeros at the beginning and end of your signal to avoid these border effects.

Comment: It should be mentioned that DFT implements the *circular* convolution unless zero padding is applied.

Comment: @Deve you're right. I have edited my answer, thanks.